# Calculating a calculable Integral using Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble with an integral:

$$\frac2L\int_L^\infty C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx$$
Where $C$ is just a constant.

I can't see how to do this, despite it apparently being rather straight forward. Something isn't making sense.

$$\frac{2C}L\int_L^\infty \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx$$
$$\frac{2C}L\left[-\frac{L}{n\pi}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\right]_L^\infty$$

But already I can't see how I can compute a divergence $\cos$.

Thank you for listening.

Comment: What is $u_0$ supposed to be?

Comment: @DavidH Sorry David, that is just a constant

Comment: What is the context of this integral? Because that looks related to the calculation of Fourier sine series coefficients.

Comment: @PolandAspect Yes I think I configured it wrong, cont here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980756/setting-up-fourier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So our integral is:

$$\frac2L\int_L^\infty C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx$$

Using improper integrals:

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{2}{L}\int_L^b C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx$$

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{2}{L} \left[C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\right]_L^b dx$$

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{2}{L}\left(C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi b}{L}\right) - C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi L}{L}\right)\right)$$

Since

$$\lim_{b\to\infty}C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi b}{L}\right) = \infty$$

The integral diverges.

Comment: I understand. I was simply trying to show it diverged

Comment: Sorry I should have known that, I wasn't trying to be rude

Comment: Its fine. You weren't trying to be rude.

Comment: It diverges, but not to infinity, so the last equality isn't correct.

Comment: Sorry yeah, I posted that and deleted it since the way I phrased it was rude

Answer (score 0):

The integral is divergent (as your computation shows).

Comment: I think I may have setup the integral incorrectly for the fourier series, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980756/setting-up-my-fourier-series-for-b-n?lq=1